# How do I format a datagridview cell to % or write the formula correct?

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing an estimating app and I am having hard a time writing formulas that give the desired results as follows:

```
                 Quantity / Production * Non productive % = Labor Hours
```

The above formula should be answered mathematically as shown below:

```
                 1000 SF /  300 SF per hour *  @10% Non Productive= 3.6 Labor hours
```

My question is how do I write a formula to calculates the labor hours correctly?

Thank you

This is my code:

```
    private void dgv1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

         {

                double cell2 = Convert.ToSingle(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);

                double cell4 = Convert.ToSingle(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value);

                double cell5 = Convert.ToSingle(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value);

                double cell6 = Convert.ToSingle(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value);

                double cell7 = Convert.ToSingle(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value);

                double cell8 = Convert.ToSingle(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value);

                double cell9 = Convert.ToSingle(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value);

                double cell10 = Convert.ToSingle(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value);

                double cell11 = Convert.ToSingle(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value);

                double cell12 = Convert.ToSingle(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value);

                double cell13 = Convert.ToSingle(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value);

                double cell14 = Convert.ToSingle(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[14].Value);

                double cell15 = Convert.ToSingle(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value);

                double cell16 = Convert.ToSingle(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[16].Value);

                double cell17 = Convert.ToSingle(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value);

                if (2.ToString() != "" && cell4.ToString() != "" && cell5.ToString() != "" && cell6.ToString() != "" && cell7.ToString() != "" && cell8.ToString() != "" && cell9.ToString() != "" && cell10.ToString() != "" && cell11.ToString() != "" && cell12.ToString() != "" && cell13.ToString() != "" && cell14.ToString() != "" && cell15.ToString() != "" && cell16.ToString() != "" && cell17.ToString() != "")
    {
        dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value = cell2 / cell4 * cell5;   // <------ This is the formula I'm talking about//

        dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value = cell6 * cell7 *cell8 *cell9;

        dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value = cell2 / cell11;

        dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value = cell13 * cell14 * cell15 * cell16;
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you read `Quantity`, `Production` and `Non productive` in your code, and how can you calculate  `Non productive` percentage? I mean What should it be devided to? the total hours? if yes, Where do you read that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Quantity / (Production * ((Non productive / Total)* 100) ) = Labor Hours`

From your code I am assuming `cell2` is Quantity, `cell4` is Production and `cell5` is Non productive.

First thing you need to do is finding out how to calculate Non productive percentage. I think (which means I am not sure) it should be calculated by `(Non productive / Total)* 100` wehre non productive according to my assumption would be `cell5` although I dont know where is total.

Then your formula would be:

```
cell2 / ( cell4 * ((cell5 / total) * 100 )))
```

Comment: I can't seem to translate this to your formula correctly. dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value = cell2 / cell4 * cell5;

Comment: What are `cell2`, `cell4` and `cell5` ?

Comment: Quantity = cell2  Production = cell4  Non Productive = cell5  Labor Hours = cell6. Non productive needs to be a percentage

Comment: in order to calculate percentage you need total which is equal to `Productive + NonProductive` do you have Productive stored somewhere?